# Swift 2.2 - the code getting crashed unless I turn off optimization (-Onone)

Tags: ios, swift, macos, recursion

This is on XCode 7.3.

If I build the code with optimization flag `-O`, it will be crashed. It is working properly without optimization (flag `-Onone`). However I want to have my code built with optimization.

Is it Swift compiler bug?

This is the code.

```
import Foundation

extension Dictionary where Key: StringLiteralConvertible, Value: AnyObject {
  func multipartFormParams(preFix preFix: String = "") -> [String: AnyObject] {
    var params: [String: AnyObject] = [:]
    for (key, value) in self {
      let subKey = preFix != "" ? "\(preFix)[\(key)]" : String(key)
      if let value = value as? [String: AnyObject] {
        // params += value.multipartFormParams(preFix: subKey) // this is my original code, however remove the operation extension += to focus on the bug.
        value.multipartFormParams(preFix: subKey) // It crash here.
      } else {
        params[subKey] = value
      }
    }
    return params
  }
}

let parameters: [String: AnyObject] = [
  "user": [
    "first_name": "first",
    "last_name": "last"
  ]
]

parameters.multipartFormParams()
```

Comment: Where does it crash?

Comment: @MarcoSantarossa See line `value.multipartFormParams(preFix: subKey) # It crash here.`.

Comment: @MartinR: the compiler does not crash, it is a runtime error.

Comment: Ok then I misread the question, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while, I found that this is related to this bug: https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-1114, change `for (key, value) in self {` to `forEach { key, value in` solved the problem.

Full working version:

```
import Foundation

extension Dictionary where Key: StringLiteralConvertible, Value: AnyObject {
  func multipartFormParams(preFix preFix: String = "") -> [String: AnyObject] {
    var params: [String: AnyObject] = [:]
    forEach { key, value in
      let subKey = preFix != "" ? "\(preFix)[\(key)]" : String(key)
      if let value = value as? [String: AnyObject] {
        // params += value.multipartFormParams(preFix: subKey) // this is my original code, however remove the operation extension += to focus on the bug.
        value.multipartFormParams(preFix: subKey) // It crash here.
      } else {
        params[subKey] = value
      }
    }
    return params
  }
}

let parameters: [String: AnyObject] = [
  "user": [
    "first_name": "first",
    "last_name": "last"
  ]
]

parameters.multipartFormParams()
```